# " Libreoffice Calc: Find correspondent of column A in column B then copy value of column B to a new column"

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I want to find words in texts like this:

```
a b c d e f g
g f e d c b a
...
```

Becomes:

```
Column A              Column B
a b c d e f g         1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
g f e d c b a         7 6 5 4 3 2 1
...                   ...
```

Based on:

```
Column A              Column B
a                     1
b                     2
c                     3
d                     4
e                     5
f                     6
g                     7
```

Each letter represents a word. And the source with correspondence comes from a different file, and is very long to just become another column in the result.

The result must include all the correspondences to a new column.

Answer (score 0):

If the list of replacement strings is not too long, then repeated use of [SUBSTITUTE](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#SUBSTITUTE) is enough.  However, from the question, it sounds like the list is too long.

So, use [APSO](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/apso-alternative-script-organizer-for-python) to run the following python macro.  Adjust the code based on the location of spreadsheets and cells.

```py
def replace_words_by_table():
    oDataSheet = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument().getSheets().getByIndex(0)
    oReplacementSheet = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument().getSheets().getByIndex(1)
    oRange = oReplacementSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1:B100")
    oReplacementArray = oRange.getDataArray()
    replacement_dict = dict(oReplacementArray)
    for row in range(2):
        oCellInput = oDataSheet.getCellByPosition(0, row)
        oCellOutput = oDataSheet.getCellByPosition(1, row)
        text = oCellInput.getString()
        for key in replacement_dict:
            text = text.replace(key, str(replacement_dict[key]))
        oCellOutput.setString(text)
```

Note: I did not take the time to write code that would perform quickly, so it may be slow for large amounts of data.

**EDIT**:

To load the files mentioned in your comment, rename `randomtext.txt` to `randomtext.csv`. Then change the first three lines of the original code to the following.

```py
from com.sun.star.beans import PropertyValue

def replace_words_by_table():
    oDesktop = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDesktop()
    args = (PropertyValue('FilterName', 0, 'Spreadseet - CSV', 0),)
    oReplacementDoc = oDesktop.loadComponentFromURL(
        "file:///C:/Users/user1/database.csv", "_default", 0, args)
    oReplacementSheet = oReplacementDoc.getSheets().getByIndex(0)
    args = (
        PropertyValue('FilterName', 0, 'Spreadseet - CSV', 0),
        PropertyValue('FilterOptions', 0, '44,34,0,,', 0),)
    oDataDoc = oDesktop.loadComponentFromURL(
        "file:///C:/Users/user1/randomtext.csv", "_default", 0, args)
    oDataSheet = oDataDoc.getSheets().getByIndex(0)
```

Filter options are described at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options.

Comment: Could you help me adjust the code? They have one sheet only, but I don't know what to set.
C:\Users\user1\database.csv
C:\Users\user1\randomtext.txt